# Iphone Development: How bad is

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

being a relative freshman in Cocoa development (I'm currently working on an iPhone app), I was wondering if an "Illegal Geometry" as reported by Interface Builder is actually harmful, or in any way hampering the functionality or performance of my application.
I really try to avoid overlapping siblings as much as possible, but sometimes, for esthetic reasons, it is just a necessity.
However, I don't notice anything if I'm doing illegal things. Will it turn against me in unexpected situations? Is it technically illegal, or is it against Apple's Human Interface Guidelines?
Thank you so much for your insight.

Comment: What's the problem with fixing it?

Comment: For instance: a UITextView has a text inset, of which it is not obvious to me how to change that. So, if I put another UITextView beneath it, but I want it to have the text align in such a way, that you cannot see that there are two Views, these Views have to overlap slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Overlaps aren't a problem.  Feel free to ignore the warnings.  Of course, make sure you are doing it in the spirit of good UI design.

The real issues are with things like negative widths/heights or other completely out of bounds settings that could crash your app.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note - apple takes its interface guidelines pretty seriously.  I know of a few people who have had their app rejected from the app store for minor infractions.

Comment: I never know whether Apple's obsession with these things is a good or bad thing.